# ZipFile extracting issue

Tags: c#, zip

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS4Kx.png)

So this is a method that gets the directory of a file (is a .JDCEDFile but its is just renamed .zip file) 
With this method i try to rename het file and extract it to a specified folder.
And show its contents into the right textboxes.
This method fails at Extracting process and i don't understand why.

```
public void OpenEncodedFile(string path)
    {
        // Variabelen + verwerking
        string defaultpath = Application.StartupPath + @"\temp";
        string defaultzip = path;
        string defaultzipRename = defaultzip.Replace(".JDCEDFile", ".zip");
        File.Move(defaultzip, defaultzipRename);
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(defaultzipRename, defaultpath);
        Input.Text = File.ReadAllText(defaultpath + @"\tempData.txt");
        Password.Text = File.ReadAllText(defaultpath + @"\tempPass.txt");
        File.Move(defaultzipRename, defaultzip);
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It doenst give an error it just shuts off.

Answer (score 0):

"path" has to be wrong, I just tested it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void openEncodedFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (openEncodedFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OpenEncodedFile(openEncodedFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

This the the code.